# How much data is created daily (source of IBM estimation)

Tags: statistics, data

I've stumbled upon [this IBM text](https://www-01.ibm.com/common/ssi/cgi-bin/ssialias?htmlfid=WRL12345USEN).

It states that:

> Every day, we create 2.5 quintillion bytes of data

It's very interesting statistic, but I couldn't find any source for this.

Does anyone know how they calculated this? Or maybe someone knows some papers showing similar/different results?

[This paper from CSA](https://downloads.cloudsecurityalliance.org/initiatives/bdwg/Big_Data_Top_Ten_v1.pdf) has the same statistic, but again without any source.

Note: The quote from IBM's text refers to data created by humanity, not by IBM alone.

Answer (score 1):

The McKinsey Global Institute published an interesting report on the topic of Big Data.
You can find it [here](https://www.mckinsey.com/~/media/McKinsey/Business%20Functions/McKinsey%20Digital/Our%20Insights/Big%20data%20The%20next%20frontier%20for%20innovation/MGI_big_data_full_report.ashx).

I don’t know where IBM go the numbers from, but this report is a good source.